# How do I stop nodejs-firestore writes from blocking the node.js event loop?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

When using the node.js client for firebase admin, calling `DocumentReference.set` blocks the nodejs event loop for approximately 200ms for every write. 200ms approximately corresponds to the latency expected by a network round-trip to and from the firestore server. This is a major cause of slowdown for my application.

The [documentation](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/DocumentReference.html#set) for `DocumentReference.set` seems to imply that this should be a non-blocking call because the method returns a promise (note that I did not include an await in the code, so I do not wait for the promise to resolve).

Is there a way to make this call not block the node.js event loop?

##### Code

```
logger.info("start of DB write")
const collectionReference = this.db.collection("notification");
logger.info("Before DB reference");
const documentReference = collectionReference.doc(key);
logger.info("Before DB write");
documentReference.set(value);
logger.info("after DB write");
```

##### Logs from the server

```
{"label":"index.js","level":"info","message":"start of DB write","timestamp":"2022-06-01T09:13:13.684Z"}
{"label":"index.js","level":"info","message":"Before DB reference","timestamp":"2022-06-01T09:13:13.684Z"}
{"label":"index.js","level":"info","message":"Before DB write","timestamp":"2022-06-01T09:13:13.684Z"}
{"label":"index.js","level":"info","message":"after DB write","timestamp":"2022-06-01T09:13:13.867Z"}
```

##### Environment details

- OS: node:16-alpine (docker image)
- Node.js version: v16.13.2
- npm version: 8.5.5
- `@google-cloud/firestore` version: 4.15.1

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this problem was caused by something I did not expect: The esbuild bundler I was using. It seems like esbuild does not play nice with firebase admin. Removing esbuild from the build process fixes the problem. Now all 4 log statements are logged at the same ms. FYI: esbuild version I used was 0.14.21 .